# Как решить задачу на с++ или си без string?

Tags: c++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу понять как работать без встроенных функций удаления элемента из строки, и если создать массив для строки, он может занять много памяти?

Comment: Из условия непонятно, что делать в случае, например, `ffuu` - словом, надо ли удалять все полностью, или только внутреннюю пару `fu`.

Comment: Код в вопросе на этом сайте приводится текстом, а не картинками!

Comment: Задаете вопрос второй раз?

Answer (score 2):

Вобщем, примерно так (проверить негде, URL проверяющей системы вы не дали):

```
int main()
{
    int c;
    int count = 0;
    do
    {
        c = getchar();
        if (c == 'f') count++;
        else
        {
            if (count)
            {
                if (c == 'u') count--;
                else
                {
                    for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
                        putchar('f');
                    putchar(c);
                    count = 0;
                }
            }
            else putchar(c);
        }
    } while(c != '.');
}
```